# The usage of On with days in informal speech

Tags: prepositions

I've read it that you could choose not to use the preposition **On** when talking about days, like " I hope i get to meet you monday." in informal speech. 
So, i was wondering, could i choose not to use **On** all the time?

Or is it better to just use **On** when talking about days in informal speech?

Comment: "This happened (on a) rainy Sunday: Lekon Chekon suddenly wondered if **on** could be ommitted in all time constructions"

Comment: I suppose it's better to use "On" always when constructing similar sentences, that way i can't just go wrong. xD

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I don't see or hear much difference in formality  between using and not using *on* with days.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, if it's clear *what* day you're talking about, and you don't attach any adjectives to it, you're free to remove the "on" from "on x-day". 
 Examples:

> It's happening on Monday == It's happening Monday :: By default, leaving off "on" implies "this" 
>   It happened on Monday at the beginning of March:: It happened Monday at the beginning of March

Non-examples:

> It happened on a rainy Monday =/= It happened a rainy Monday (I think technically this is a proper construction, but I can almost guarantee you won't hear people say this)